# CircleCI reports "No workflow" when creating a tagged release

Tags: circleci

I want to build a CircleCI workflow which builds and pushes to ECR only when I create a tagged release in Github.

I have the following CircleCI workflow:

```yaml
workflows:
  test-build-and-push-image:
    jobs:
      - get_python_dependencies
      - unit_tests:
          requires:
            - get_python_dependencies
      - aws-ecr/build-and-push-image:
          name: build-and-push-to-ecr
          repo: ${CIRCLE_PROJECT_REPONAME}
          tag: ${CIRCLE_SHA1}
          create-repo: true
          requires:
            - unit_tests
          filters:
            tags:
              only: /.*/
            branches:
              ignore: /.*/
```

As I understand it, the filters on `build-and-push-to-ecr` are supposed to mean:

- Run this job for any tag whatsoever
- Don't run this job when pushing to any branch

But when I create a tagged release I get:

[image: No workflow]

Why aren't my filters working?

Answer (score 3):

A very close reading of the docs under [Executing workflows for a git tag](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/workflows/#executing-workflows-for-a-git-tag) reveals a well-hidden detail:

> if a job requires any other jobs (directly or indirectly), you must use regular expressions to specify tag filters for those jobs.

In other words, every job in the workflow must have the same filters for the build and push job to happen.

We can keep things a bit DRYer using `&` anchors:

```yaml
workflows:
  test-build-and-push-image:
    jobs:
      - get_python_dependencies:
          filters: &tagged
            # We only want to trigger this workflow on tags, not pushes to branches.
            branches:
              ignore: /.*/
            tags:
              # Trigger on every tag
              only: /.*/
      - unit_tests:
          requires:
            - get_python_dependencies
          <<: *tagged
      - aws-ecr/build-and-push-image:
          name: build-and-push-to-ecr
          repo: ${CIRCLE_PROJECT_REPONAME}
          tag: ${CIRCLE_SHA1}
          create-repo: true
          requires:
            - unit_tests
          <<: *tagged
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post your own resolution. This SO post helped me sort out my CI config today. Cheers!