# Executing a CircleCI job only when tag matches a certain pattern

Tags: circleci, circleci-workflows

I have the following workflow definition for a CircleCI build

```yaml
workflows:
  version: 2
  default:
    jobs:
      - verify
      - tests_3_1:
          requires:
            - verify
      - tests_5_0:
          requires:
            - verify
      - pack:
          requires:
            - tests_3_1
            - tests_5_0
      - push:
          requires:
            - pack
          context:
            - GitHub
          filters:
              tags:
                only: /^v(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[1-9]\d*)(?:-((?:0|[1-9]\d*|\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*)(?:\.(?:0|[1-9]\d*|\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*))*))?(?:\+([0-9a-zA-Z-]+(?:\.[0-9a-zA-Z-]+)*))?$/
              branches:
                ignore: /.*/
```

The idea is to:

- run `verify`, `test_3_1`, `test_5_0`, `pack` on all commits
- on top of the jobs above, run the job `push` when on master and with a tag that matches a semver version prepended by a `v`

For some reason no build is triggered when the commit is tagged. I am not sure if the problem is in the filter or in the regex not matching the build tags.

For now I tried `v0.1.0-preview-0001` which matches on RegexPal.

[image: build is not triggered]

Could you suggest any improvement? I see there is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65355175/circleci-reports-no-workflow-when-creating-a-tagged-release) that is pretty similar but I have issues implementing the suggested solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by specifying a tag regex filter for every job before `push` as shown in [the documentation](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/workflows/#executing-workflows-for-a-git-tag).

```yaml
workflows:
  version: 2
  default:
    jobs:
      - verify:
          filters:
            tags:
              only: /.*/
      - tests_3_1:
          requires:
            - verify
          filters:
            tags:
              only: /.*/
      - tests_5_0:
          requires:
            - verify
          filters:
            tags:
              only: /.*/
      - pack:
          requires:
            - tests_3_1
            - tests_5_0
          filters:
            tags:
              only: /.*/
      - push:
          requires:
            - pack
          context:
            - GitHub
          filters:
              tags:
                only: /^v(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[1-9]\d*)(?:-((?:0|[1-9]\d*|\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*)(?:\.(?:0|[1-9]\d*|\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*))*))?(?:\+([0-9a-zA-Z-]+(?:\.[0-9a-zA-Z-]+)*))?$/
              branches:
                ignore: /.*/
```